# multiple file output in hadoop mapreduce streaming

Tags: java, python, hadoop, mapreduce

Im using hadoop map and reduce  program . And i need to read a multiple file and output it into multiple files

Example

```
Input \  one.txt 
         two.txt 
         three.txt 

Output \ 
         one_out.txt
         two_out.txt
```

I need to get some thing like this. How can i achieve  this.

Kindly help me

Thanks

Comment: you cannot control the names of files generated by MR. But if you use file input format, every file will be passed on to a different mapper eventually creating separate output file unless the file is quite large.

Comment: @AnkurShanbhag - Ok . Naming doesnt matter  i need to have a  separate o/p file for each i/p file

Answer (score 1):

- If the file size is small, you can simply use **FileInputFormat**, and hadoop will internally spawn a **separate mapper task for every file**, which will eventually generate output file for corresponding input file (if there are no reducers involved).
- If the file is huge, you need to write a custominput format, and specify `isSplittable(false)`. It will ensure that hadoop does not split your file across mappers and will not generate multiple output files per input file